# Remove number from iMessage to use on non iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages

I had an iPhone and I used iMessage on it. I didn't mind getting some of the messages to my laptop. But recently I switched back to a very old phone I had that is not a smart phone. Now I am receiving some texts to my laptop and not to my phone at all! This is frustrating because I don't want to have to check my laptop and my phone for messages.

I would like to change this so that I only receive messages to my phone, not my laptop, because I don't even have an iPhone anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the same number that you had on your iPhone and registered with iMessage, you need to remove it from the service to be able to receive normal SMS messages from iMessage users on your new, non-Apple phone.

Please go to [Deregister iMessage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage) and follow the steps described on the page.